# Selector to Static Func with Parameters in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, swift3, selector

Is it possible to have a selector to a static function with parameters in Swift?

The syntax I tried is this:

```
  button.addTarget(VCPresenter.self, action: #selector(VCPresenter.handleBackButton(_:parentNavigationController!)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and the static method is this

```
  @objc public static func handleBackButton(_ controller: UINavigationController) {
    controller.popViewController(animated: true);
}
```

When I compile, I get

> Error:(24, 56) argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: You still need a `NSObject` subclass instance for the target argument (perhaps a class shared one), the selector can represent a static method indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I made new project with single view application and this work. Let me know if this work for you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonAction(x:y:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc public static func buttonAction(x: Int, y: String){
        print("Test")
    }
}
```